# Finding a "trail" in 2-D dimention arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, multidimensional-array, pseudocode

I don't know how to figure out this question, I am just a beginner to computer science.

The input will be 2D array A[n][n] numbers, representing the topographic map of the geographic surface. Also among the input will be a starting location (r,c). referring to entry A[r][c]

If you were planning hiking trails you would be bound by the differences in elevation between neighboring entries. A person could traverse between 2 adjacent locations, if their elevations differ by no more than 2). Adjacency follows just the 4 standard compass directions, (so I assume no diagonals). Therefore , a point on the map is considered reachable if it is traversable from A[r][c] through any sequence of adjacent entires.

Write an algorithm that computes all of the reachable locations. The output will be another 2D array R[n][n] with true/fals values. (I assume true means reachable, false means unreachable)

If i understand this question correctly, I can create following matrix. (suppose A[10][10] looks like this from A[0][0]:)

```
50 51 54 58 60 60 60 63 68 71
48 52 51 59 60 60 63 63 69 70
44 48 52 55 58 61 64 64 66 69
44 46 53 52 57 60 60 61 65 68
42 45 50 54 59 61 63 63 66 70
38 42 46 56 56 63 64 61 64 62
36 40 44 50 58 60 66 65 62 61
36 39 42 49 56 62 67 66 65 60
30 36 40 47 50 64 64 63 62 60
50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
```

Both south and east are traversable from A[0][0] so reachable entries would be:

```
50 51 54 58 60 60 60 63 68 71
48 52 51 59 60 60 63 63 69 70
44 48 52 55 58 61 64 64 66 69
44 46 53 52 57 60 60 61 65 68
42 45 50 54 59 61 63 63 66 70
38 42 46 56 56 63 64 61 64 62
36 40 44 50 58 60 66 65 62 61
36 39 42 49 56 62 67 66 65 60
30 36 40 47 50 64 64 63 62 60
50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
```

so I can conclude that my resulting array should be

```
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Our professor ask us to implement this in pseudocode. I don't know how to do comparisons for two neighbor points and 4 directions of the point. Anyone can give me some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just flood fill. You need a queue and an index-addressable vector of "visited" flags. Put the root into the queue. Whist the queue is not empty, take the first element, and check for reachable locations N,S,E,W. Then check if they have been visited. If not, mark them as visited, and put them in the queue.